# How to always include margins when not enough screen width in css?

Tags: html, css, margin

In css, I have a div with margin, but on small width, the margin-right gets removed from the element.

see this https://jsfiddle.net/d184wqhc/13/

```
<div class="A">
    <div>A</div>
</div>
```

css

```
.A div {
  margin:30px;
  width:500px;
  height:100px;
  background-color:cyan;
  word-break: break-all;
}
```

When there is enough room, it looks like this

[image]

but when I shrink the screen width more, it looks like

[image]

as you can see, the scroll bar has moved all the way right, but the margin-right spacing is gone.

How can I keep the whole text within the div with the cyan background and keep the spacing included within the scrollbar?

Thanks

Comment: That's not margin, that's padding.

Comment: but im not using any padding css

Answer (score 1):

You can set the `div` as `display: inline-block`, `inline-flex`, or `inline-table`, so that the width won't get limited by the container, and any `padding` and `margin` will apply.

Also set `min-width: calc(100% - 60px)` if you need it to be full width initially.

```css
div {
  margin: 30px;
  background-color: cyan;
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: calc(100% - 60px);
}
```

```html
<div>AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because the content is overflowing the element. If you look at the element the background color (cyan) is only going to a certain point, and then stopping. That is where the margin is. Just add `word-break: break-all;` and it will stop overflowing. https://jsfiddle.net/pc7ekwd1/2/

Comment: How can I set it so that, all the text has the cyan background, and all of that with the margin spacing, is fully contained in the scrollbar?

Comment: i updated the jsfiddle, the break all doesnt work there.

Comment: I updated it to not be text, more like a inner div box. Break all doesn't work on that.